# Ruby on rails user authentication using linux passwd file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, authentication

Is there an authentication plugin for rails which uses the host system's `/etc/passwd` file to provide user/password information?  The goal is to provide user login to a rails app for the same users who already have local login accounts to the linux machine hosting the rails app.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your system uses PAM (h ttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules), most linux distributions do, you might want
to look at Ruby/PAM.

Or you could try and use the authlogic gem + authogic_pam http://github.com/nbudin/authlogic_pam. I think the